# Cannot add Conditional Forwarder in Active Directory

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

Right now, I have three forests I'm trying to create trusts between.

Let's call them `hopelessn00b.local`, `hopelessn00b.com` and `internal.hopelessn00b.com`.

I got trusts configured between `hopelessn00b.local` and `hopelessn00b.com`, as well as between `hopelessn00b.local` and `internal.hopelessn00b.com`, but when I went to set up the trust between `hopelessn00b.com` and `internal.hopelessn00b.com`, it bombed out, because `hopelessn00b.com` cannot contact `internal.hopelessn00b.com`.

So, I checked DNS, and sure enough, there's no forwarders or stub zones or anything that might tell `hopelessn00b.com` how to get to `internal.hopelessn00b.com`.  I checked my `hopelessn00b.local` forest, and it was using a conditional forwarder to reach both the other domains, so I tried to set up a conditional forwarder on `hopelessn00b.com` with the IPs of my `internal.hopelessn00b.com` domain controllers.  That fails with a "zone configuration error," after telling me that my `internal.hopelessn00b.com` domain controllers are not authoritative for the `internal.hopelessn00b.com` domain (they are).  I assume that's because `internal.hopelessn00b.com` is a DNS sub-domain of `hopelessn00b.com`, even though they're completely different and unrelated AD forests.

Functional levels involved are 2008 R2 and 2012, if it makes a difference (but I don't think it does), and I'd very much like to get these trusts set up so that I can migrate everything off these improperly named forests and then blow them away, so only `internal.hopelessn00b.com` will remain.

Accordingly, my questions are:

1. Is a conditional forwarder the thing I want here, or should I be using something else? (Stub zone, maybe?)
2. How do I force (or finesse) `hopelessn00b.com` into taking my word for it that the DCs for `internal.hopelessn00b.com` are actually authoritative for `internal.hopelessn00b.com`?

Comment: Delegate, you must... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255248

Comment: @RyanRies  But there are no child domains at play here, nor do I wish there to be.  I don't want the best-practices-compliant `internal.hopelessn00b.com` AD forest to become dependent on the soon-to-be-obliterated `hopelessn00b.com` AD forest.  Is a delegation still applicable in this case?

Comment: @HopelessN00b: Ryan is correct, you need to dns delegate. Even if there as you say is no AD child domain, there is in dns by way of namespace. On the bright side, when you have obliterated to your hearts content you could simply remove the delegation and refer/forward dns clients directly to the (not-)child domain. Sorry, can't work out how to phrase that last bit, I hope you understand my intention :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the two domains, even though they are in unrelated AD forests, are part of the same DNS namespace, [you must use DNS delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753500.aspx).